# Uniform Initialization Syntax in complex hierarchy construction?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++11

I'm using GCC 4.4.5.

Here is the reproduction of my problem :

```
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:

    Test( int a, int b = 42 ) : m_a( a ), m_b( b ) {}

private:

    int m_a;
    int m_b;    
};

typedef std::vector<Test> TestList;


class TestMaster
{
public:

    TestMaster( TestList tests = TestList() ) : m_tests( tests ) {}


private:

    TestList m_tests;

};
```

Now, this works :

```
int main()
{

    TestList test_list = { 15, 22, 38 };


    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't compile :

```
class TestManager : public TestMaster
{
public:

    TestManager()
        : TestMaster( { { 42, 54, 94 } } ) //?
    {}


};



int main()
{

    TestManager test_manager;


    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe I just don't use the correct syntax? Or is GCC wrong?

The error :

```
g++ -std=c++0x hello_world.cpp
hello_world.cpp: In constructor \u2018TestManager::TestManager()\u2019:
hello_world.cpp:38: erreur: no matching function for call to \u2018TestMaster::TestMaster(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)\u2019
hello_world.cpp:24: note: candidats sont: TestMaster::TestMaster(TestList)
hello_world.cpp:21: note:                 TestMaster::TestMaster(const TestMaster&)
```

I also tried a simpler way of doing the same (without inheritance) :

```
TestMaster test_master = { { 42, 54, 94 } };
```

With the same errror.

Any idea? I can't see why the semantic wouldn't work here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got too many levels of construction going on. Initializer lists only work at one level, so you need to tell it that you want the list to apply to the `TestList` parameter of `TestMaster`:

```
TestMaster test_master(TestList({42,54,94}))
```

and then the same in the constructor of `TestManager`:

```
TestManager()
    : TestMaster( TestList( { 42, 54, 94 } ) )
{}
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought. The inner braces would return a list-like object proper, and the outer braces would take that object and would let it be interpreted as a comma-seperated list of values of the list-like object type, but what is inside the outer braces is already an object. But this little text of mine is a lot more confusing than the answer above `:s`.

Comment: So i would have to add an std::intializer_list<> constructor to allow the syntax I used?

Comment: Yes, if `TestMaster` had a `std::initializer_list` constructor then this could be used to initialize the `m_tests` member.

Comment: I think that this should work: `: TestMaster( { 42, 54, 94 } )`. I.e just omit one of the braces. If you don't omit them, what you get is a `{ { ... } }` trying to initialize a `vector<Test>`. This would yield to `{ ... }` trying to initialize a `Test` (by using `vector<Test>`'s initializer list constructor). But `Test` does not have a 3-argument ctor, so this will fail. By omitting one brace level, `{ ... }` initializing `vector<Test>` will work fine.